# Integration Branch or not?

Tags: sql-server, tfs, sql-server-data-tools

In an environment (SQL Server, TFS, SSDT, VS) with around a dozen TFS SQL Server Data Tools Database Projects per solution (with database projects only) with four to five simultaneous branches, would you recommend using an integration branch or not? And why (not)?
Is it worth the overhead?
If not, how do we best perform merges between branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It totally depends on your teams workflow on how your branches relate to your workflow and release strategy.  Let me give 2 different examples of where you would want an integration branch, and where you might not.

## Example #1

You have 5 Feature Branches, some or all of them will be integrated together to create the next release.  In this case you clearly want an integration branch.

## Example #2

You have 3 branches representing v1 - v3 of the software that are all under development simultaneously.  In this case you might not need an integration branch.  All v1 code should be merged into v2/v3 branches, but not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! We have five development teams that will use one branch each, they overlap in time and they all have different start/end dates. We will release only one branch at a time. All code from all branches will eventually be merged in to the trunk/baseline and sometimes forwarded to the other branches. I guess that is most similar to your example #2? I'd prefer to skip the integration branch, but then how do we best merge a specific change from branch one to branch two before release? And what if we happen to need to apply a checkin from branch 2 into branch 1?

Comment: I consider trunk/baseline to be an integration branch.

Comment: ok but then you also have a main/production/live/.. branch as well?

Comment: Yes, you'd have a "main" branch as well as your integration branch, but if that's your method it sounds like the safest thing to do. We're actually moving that way now because our branches are promoted through the environments at different times.

Comment: I don't believe having branches that match environments (e.g. Production) is a good practice.  You make builds from a branch, and that **build** may be deployed to multiple environments over time.  Branches should follow the workflow of your code integrations, not your deployment workflow/pipeline/environments.